# Lots of path on screen makes tooltip slow on iPhone

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, ionic-framework

I am drawing 21 * 9 windBarbs in my d3 chart using PATH. 
Sample path looks like this:

```
<path marker-start="url(#meteo-barbheadLight)" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.5" class="meteo-aloft-barb meteo-aloft-barb-group-0 moderate" d="M1 2 L8 2 M0 0 L1 2 Z" transform="translate(0, 225.64285714285714) scale(1.875), rotate(339.35300899956496, 0, 0), translate(-4, -2)" style="opacity: 0.2;"></path>
```

This is working fine on desktop web browser. But when I run it on iOS safari. Due to some reason tooltip-trendline performance becomes very poor.

I am not sure what is causing this issue. I even tried to isolate these barbs from trendline -tooltip functionality, but still it is slow. If I dont draw these barbs then tooltip is pretty smooth.

So question is :

1) Are those 21 * 9 barbs making page so heavy that tooltip is having lag on mobile browser?

2) What can be a better way to do this?

Application URL:

http://ec2.buser.net/bnforecast/meteogramv2/#!/app/dashboard?start=KBTP&product=MAV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this is either draw all those paths inside a canvas instead of SVG or just export those paths to canvas using canvg library and then remove SVG path container  element. Canvas is way lighter than SVG.

Also, one tip is to use **display: none** instead of opacity for performance boost.